# jqGrid Search UI Not Refreshing/Redrawing

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid to get back some data. The grid get's rendered with data and when it's loaded I add a filter and reload the grid. This basically removes certain files from the view upon first page load.

I have a checkbox on the page which toggles between two filters (including this data & excluding this data), each time it applies the filter then reloads the grid.

If I click the search button, the search popup displays my filter that I've just added.
If I then close it, change the filter through clicking this checkbox (it changes the data), then open the search popup again, my newly applied and obviously working filter is not displayed, only the previous filter!? No matter how many times I toggle the filter with the check box (which every time works to change the data), the filter in the popup does not change to what the current filter really is. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution...

```
    "use strict";
    /*global xmlJsonClass, jQuery, $  */
    var rp_ge = {};
    $.jgrid.extend({
    searchGrid : function (p) {
        p = $.extend({
            recreateFilter: false,
            drag: true,
            sField:'searchField',
            sValue:'searchString',
            sOper: 'searchOper',
            sFilter: 'filters',
```

**recreateFilter** was being set to false from within the library JS file on every 'reload' of the grid. So every time I added a new filter this was being reset to NOT recreate the filters in the popup.

Setting this to true solved the problem.